# Google Play Integrity API result UNEVALUATED after mobile restart

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-integrity-api

I have released my app with google play integrity api.
App works after device integrity check success

```
"deviceIntegrity": {
    "deviceRecognitionVerdict": ["MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY", "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY"]
  },
```

I found issue with some user facing the issue that device passes device integrity at the time of install
but after restart device, deviceIntegrity check failed

here is response what i found during debugging after restart

```
{
   "requestDetails": {
     "requestPackageName": "com.my.package",
     "timestampMillis": "1674455009345",
     "nonce": "Y29tLm1hbnRyYS5yZHNlcnZpY2UyMDIzMDEyMzExNTIzMjajHDrnJ9vtl2AfC1fUdEDJmD_HfvFtcpc\u003d"
   },
   "appIntegrity": {
     "appRecognitionVerdict": "UNEVALUATED"
   },
   "deviceIntegrity": {
   },
   "accountDetails": {
     "appLicensingVerdict": "UNEVALUATED"
   }
 }
```

I have search about UNEVALUATED result

"Application integrity was not evaluated. A necessary requirement was missed, such as the device not being trustworthy enough."

But the issue accures only after restarting the android device

I Hope some one can help us on this issue.

Comment: I'm also implementing the Integrity check. I'll try the restart test and I'll inform you if it happens also to me. In your opinion, do you think that the check is needed everytime the user open the App (onCreate)? Or it is enough at the first install and why?

Comment: @user2342558 if you are checking app integrity it is ok to check one time when installed, I am checking  device integrity so i am checking it one time after every reboot, rest is on your requirement.

Comment: I want to check the app, device, and licensing.

Comment: We also see this error. This breaks quite a lot of devices currently

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your play integrity SDK this issue resolve in new version.

`implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.2.0'`

For more information check [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267213059)